# React-native-router-flux scene render multiple times

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

So I use react-native-router-flux and here is my scene

```
<Scene key="changePassword" component={ChangePassword} title="Change Password"/>
```

And I have this button which will route to that scene when clicked

```
<Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => Actions.changePassword()}>
```

**If I click the button for many times, multiple scene will pop up.**

Is there any way to prevent this? Thank you for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to give delay if the button has been clicked, put local state like this:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      inClick: false
    }
  }
```

and add this function :

```
onClickButton = () => {
    this.setState({ inClick: true })
    Actions.register()
    setTimeout(function() { this.setState({inClick: false}); }.bind(this), 2000);
  }
```

and in your button should be like this :

```
<Button warning block style={styles.button} onPress={ !this.state.inClick ? this.onClickButton : null}>
```

Hope that can help you, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to disable the button if it has been clicked , there's a prop called disabled in react native button.

```
function handleButtonClick(){
  this.setState({ disabled: true });
  Actions.changePassword();
}


<Button onPress={()=> this.handleButtonClick()} disabled={this.state.disabled} />
```