# React-native-router-flux prevent multiple taps

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux and I'm facing an issue,
when I click on a Button multiple times, It navigates to the same screen multiple times, how can I prevent multiple taps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here : [Scene render multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616618/react-native-router-flux-scene-render-multiple-times?rq=1)

You really should start using [React Native Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) instead of Router Flux